# Отслеживание входа/выхода пользователей из системы

Tags: c#, windows-service, служба

Необходимо реализовать службу, которая будет отслеживать пользователей, которые вошли или вышли из системы и писать эту информацию в лог.

Какими методами можно отследить событие входа/выхода пользователя из системы?

Пробовал переопределять метод OnSessionChange:

```cs
protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
{  
    writer.WriteLine(changeDescription.SessionId.ToString());
    writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

В таком случае в лог ничего не пишется.

Answer (score 1):

А про `CanHandleSessionChangeEvent` вы не забыли?

```
    // в конструкторе
    CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
```

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо. Но получаю я всё-равно не то, что хотел. SessionId возвращает число, а мне необходимо получить имя пользователя.
Может быть Вы знаете, как это сделать?